# forkjoin deprecated in Angular 10 alternative

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs

Below is my code:

```
 async getBranchDetails()  ----component  method

  {
    let banks = this.bankDataService.getBanks();
    let branchTypes = this.branchDataService.getBranchTypes();

    forkJoin([banks,branchTypes]).subscribe(results => {
              this.setFormBankData(results[0]);
              this.setFormBranchTypeData(results[1]);
            });
  }
```

----service

```
 async getBanks(): Promise<IBankResponse[]> {
        return await  this.httpClient.get<Result<IBankResponse[]>>(baseUrl + '/Bank/GetBanks')
        .pipe(map( res => res.data)).toPromise();
    }
```

Fork join is showing deprecated. Is there any alternative use with `async`/`await`. Thanks.

EDIT: **i dont no whether it isright or not  but used asyn/await..My final code as below**

```
  async getBranchDetails()

  {
    let banks =  await this.bankDataService.getBanks();
    let branchTypes= await this.branchDataService.getBranchTypes();
    this.setFormBankData(banks);
    this.setFormBranchTypeData(branchTypes);
   
  }
```

Comment: `forkJoin` only works with Observables, but your functions seem to return Promises

Comment: You can use flatMap for observable requests

Comment: If you want to save yourself time in the future, don't use promises in Angular, @JSONDerulo is correct.

Comment: @json actually service is already written which returns promises..what is the best option to join ..thanks

Comment: @Ajt have a look at my answer...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are mixing Observables and Promises. Either use Observables and RxJS, or stick to Promises.

**Observables approach** (recommended):

```
getBanks(): Observable<IBankResponse[]> {
   return this.httpClient.get(baseUrl + '/Bank/GetBanks')
     .pipe(map(res => res.data));
}
```

```
const banks$ = this.bankDataService.getBanks();
const branchTypes$ = this.branchDataService.getBranchTypes();

forkJoin([banks$, branchTypes$]).subscribe(results => {
  this.setFormBankData(results[0]);
  this.setFormBranchTypeData(results[1]);
});
```

**Promises approach**:

```
getBanks(): Promise<IBankResponse[]> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Result<IBankResponse[]>>(baseUrl + '/Bank/GetBanks')
    .pipe(map( res => res.data)).toPromise();
}
```

When working with Promises, you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all requests to finish:

```
const banks = this.bankDataService.getBanks();
const branchTypes = this.branchDataService.getBranchTypes();

Promise.all([banks, branchTypes]).then(results => {
  this.setFormBankData(results[0]);
  this.setFormBranchTypeData(results[1]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..one last query in observable / promise  2 different request / only one (request goes to server?

Comment: i have updated final code in question. Please let me know if it wrong

Comment: @Ajt Your final code is also fine. But please not that the requests will be made sequentially and not simultaneously. If you use my code example, both requests will be made simultaneously, which is usually a little bit faster.